# Is there a way to animate the size of the header in the HeaderFooterLayout?

Tags: javascript, famo.us

Is it possible to animate the size of the header in a HeaderFooterLayout? I am trying to change it's size with an animation but I am not seeing any API for this. So I was wondering about a technique for doing it.

Comment: I suppose I can use a sequence layout and animate the surfaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a Transitionable. This is done by the following:

1. Create a transition for the animation:

   ```
   var transition = {
       duration: 400,
       curve: Easing.inOutQuad
   };
   ```
2. Set the start & end pixel counts:

   ```
   var start = open ? 200 : 100;
   var end = open ? 100 : 200;
   ```
3. Instantiate your new Transitionable with the starting pixel count:

   ```
   var transitionable = new Transitionable(start);
   ```
4. Create the function that will be executed to apply the pixel count:

   ```
   var prerender = function () {
       layout.setOptions({
           headerSize: transitionable.get()
       })
   };
   ```
5. Attache the function to the Engine event:

   ```
   Engine.on('prerender', prerender);
   ```
6. Add transition to end state to the queue of pending transitions:

   ```
   transitionable.set(end, transition, complete);
   ```

Here is a working fiddle for you to reference: http://jsfiddle.net/Mabuti/4or8nxh4/
In full disclosure I did use the following post as a point of reference: [famo.us: can I animate the header/footer heights of a header footer layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668621/famo-us-can-i-animate-the-header-footer-heights-of-a-header-footer-layout) but I tried to add some context to the process.

You could also review the Transitionable documentation to see better understand what it is doing: https://famo.us/docs/transitions/Transitionable

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the prerender functionality. I'll give this a shot later today and mark the answer

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use the famous-flex LayoutController and HeaderFooterLayout.
The code is pretty straightforward:

```
var LayoutController = require('famous-flex/LayoutController');
var HeaderFooterLayout = require('famous-flex/layouts/HeaderFooterLayout');

// Create header/content surface/views
var header = new Surface(..);
var content = new Surface(..);

// Create header-footer layout
var layout = new LayoutController({
    layout: HeaderFooterLayout,
    layoutOptions: {
        headerSize: 40
    },
    flow: true,             // this causes a smooth transition when changing the header-size
    reflowOnResize: false,  // do not reflow on resize
    dataSource: {
        header: header,
        content: content
    }
});

...

// Change the height of the header (because flow is enabled,
// this will automatically cause it to smoothly animate from
// the old height to the new height)
layout.setLayoutOptions({
    headerSize: 100
});
```

Library: https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex